# Android: How to get height of widget in pixels?

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I want to get exact height of widget in pixels in AppWidgetProvider class. After observation I can see that 1 block height of widget is different on 2 devices, although they are both xxxhdpi. So I want to get Height in pixels to make right calculations. I don't mean minHeight, which is 40dp equivalent in pixels in my case.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion,`view.getHeight` returns pixels value.To  make right calculations,`dp` rather `px` is useful

Comment: That's the problem. I don't have access to view

Comment: Have you worked on widgets? It is whole different system, then activities and fragments

Answer (score -3):

Every view in Android (widgets are views as well) has two public methods: getWidth() and getHeight() that will return their actual size on screen. More details can be found here under **Size, Padding, and Margins.** [View API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Edit: Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42419929/edit you would set the layout using:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.example_appwidget);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
```

From the RemoteViews documentation, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html you can get the ID of the root layout by `views.getLayoutId()` It seems to me like you should be able to use that ID to find the layout and then continue to use getHeight.

Comment: It is not View. AppWidgetProvider extends BroadCastReceiver

Comment: I have not done much with widgets but they do have a layout so there is a view somewhere. There must be a way to access the layout correct?

Comment: I noticed in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider that you use RemoteViews for inflating the layout. You can get the root layout from there, so it seems like you could just get the root layout and then use getHeight?

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I couldn't find a way to get view by its id. like findViewById(). I'm not sure if there is a way to do it. It is strange system here. For example, you can't get textview directly and set text to it. You must use: remoteViews.setTextViewText(idOfTextView, text); So i can't get any view by its Id, as far as i tried.

Comment: You have a context, so you should be able to get to find by id from that.